# A definitive guide to Url Encoding in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, urlencode

I am starting to realise that there are about a bazillion different methods for encoding urls in .NET.
I keep finding new ones. They all work slightly differently, but they all have essentially the same summary comments.

Does anyone have a definitive matrix that shows the exact differences between the following methods:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode
HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode
Server.UrlEncode
Uri.EscapeUriString
Uri.EscapeDataString
```

... are they any more?

Also it would be good to match these up with use-cases e.g.:

- Urls in href attributes of a tags
- Urls to be displayed to the user in HTML
- Urls as querystring values (i.e. to be sent in GET requests)
- Urls to be sent in POST requests
  etc

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200808220102/http://geekswithblogs.net/mikehuguet/archive/2009/08/16/134123.aspx) has a listing of specific character differences.